# How to get 'aria-label' attribute of <a> tag using VBA

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

How to get 'aria-label' attribute of  tag when  contains child elements using VBA

```vb
<a class=------------">Update Hire job</a>
```

I Want this text "Update Hire job" and click the link which is linked with that text
I am Using the below code and it is not working. :(

```vb
Set alllinks = doc.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each Hyperlink In alllinks
 If InStr(Hyperlink.innerText, "Update Hire job details") > 0 Then
        Hyperlink.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

> ```vb
> <tbody>
>   <!-- Irrelevant Code Not Typed -->
>   <tr id="tr_8577F437734C433CE0538CC810AC9286" aria-label="Update Hire job details" headers="task" scope="row">
>     <div> data-swf-tast-is-claimable="true" data-swf-task-is-actionable="true" data-swf-task-status="null" data-swf-task-is-reopenable="false" data-swf-task-ID="8577F437734C433CE0538CC810AC9286">
>     <span class="control">
>       <a class="name" href="/wps/moportal/$tenant/ICantBeBotheredToTypeThisAllOutEither/">Update Hire job details</a>
> ```

[Original HTML Code as Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1ykF.png)

Comment: Please include more of the html without removing  attributes and what does not work mean? Is the element selected but doesn't click? Is there an error message? And there is no aria-label shown. There is the innerText of an a  tag possibly though the html isn't correctly shown.

Comment: it is not clicked. no error is also popping up.

Comment: can you include more of the html? And have you tried adding a click event to the element?

Comment: i have uploaded one image. Class name is not unique and href is dynamic and i have to click that activity with either aria-label or inner text. and all the IDs which is showing in blue color,, all are dynamic.

Comment: Please use the snippet tool via [edit] to add html, not as an image as we can't copy that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be able to use the aria-label value in a css selector

```
ie.document.querySelector("th[aria-label='Update Hire Job Details'] a").Click
```

Which might be simplified to:

```
ie.document.querySelector("[aria-label='Update Hire Job Details'] a").Click
```

[Attribute css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: One error is coming. Object variable or With block variable not set. when i am doing step over,, it is working. what i have to declare for object variable?

Comment: That implies one of two things normally. Either trying to quickly to find or wrong access path to element. Try adding Application.Wait Now + Timeserial(0,0,3) before the line above.What happens?

Comment: your pasted code is slightly different from image. I saw the aria label associated with a th, not tr, element in the image. You have redacted import html within the tr